# Best way to convert C++ object <--> C struct?

Tags: c++, c, object, struct

So basically I am trying to integrate a custom C library into an existing C++ project. I have various C++ objects that will need to be stored/loaded into a C DB and interface with various C functions. I need to convert my C++ objects into C structs, and back again. I have made progress, but am running into memory allocation issues.

I know I haven't included any code here, but I am just wondering if there are any general tips for this task? I have seen the void* used in extern "C" for generic C++ objects, but I really need to load/save data from/to C++ objects and C structs.

If I haven't worded this correctly, please ask!

Comment: It might help to show an example of what you're looking at.  Is this a collection of plain old data or something else?  `struct` and `class` are really the same thing with different default permissions.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: `class` and `struct` are essentially the same in C++, but certainly not in C.  You could not pass a polymorphic C++ class object to C code that is expecting a flat C-style struct, the layouts would not match.  So outside of trivial cases, there is likely going to need some conversions made from one to the other.  But you are right, we need an example of the OP's use case.

Answer (score 2):

Use `extern "C"` to declare your C structures:

```
extern "C" {
    struct some_c_struct {
        int field1;
        char *p;
    };
};
```

Then, in your C++ code you can use `some_c_struct` just like any other C++ `class` or `struct`, with guaranteed C compatibility, and successfully pass them to and from the C code library that you're using.

Practically speaking, the `extern "C"` declaration isn't needed, but all the language lawyers demand it. Additionally, your struct cannot use any C++-specific features, like virtual functions.